# Trouble downloading DLC's

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I have the expansion pass so how would I download the DLC's and if so can you tell me how on an Xbox 360 possibly or redirect me?

Answer (score 1):

Just start the game if you have downloaded the expansion pass.(do not download the extra DLC(expansion packs) packs from the marketplace, you already have them). Begin the game, the game will recognise this( a lot of the DLC is on disk or part of the compatibility packs), go to the first vendor on the left as you enter the tower, you should be able to get a DLC sparrow from there or go to Crucible and check to see if you can go into "The Dark Below" playlists. If so, all good. Even if you play on a non DLC Xbox you will not lose your DLC items.